Prove a preference preserved under limits if and only if its upper and lower contour is closed
I'm concerned with the reverse direction, that upper and lower contour is closed implies the preference is continuous, that is  for any sequence $x_n$ and $y_n$, $x_n\succcurlyeq y_n$ for all $n$, then if $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$, we have $x\succcurlyeq y$.
I have read some of the proofs of it, but it seems all of them have utilised that the preference is transitive. Included the solution manual for MWG, it states use Proposition 1.B.1, which is the proposition under rationality. But isn't it that we don't have rationality here?

Without any more assumptions, this need not be true. Here is an economically nonsensical but mathematically fine example: Consider the following relation on the real line: $x\succeq y$ holds if and only if $x=y$ and $x$ is a rational number. The graph of this relation is $G=\{(q,q)\mid q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$, a set that is clearly not closed. So there exist sequences $\langle (x_m,y_n)$ converging to $(x,y)$ satisfying $x_n\succeq y_n$ for all $n$ but $x\succeq y$ does not hold. However, all upper and lower contour sets are empty or contain a single point and are, therefore, closed.
